# SQL to find the maximum number in a grouped column result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display only the highest "TotalSales" after grouping by empname column.

Please below is my SQL statement.

```
select e.empname as "EmployeeName", sum(p.price) as "TotalSales" 
from employees e
join orders o on e.employee_id = o.empid
join products p on o.orderID = p.orderID
group by e.empname
order by TotalSales desc
```

[image: Output of my query]

Comment: Add a TOP 1 ... For Example Select TOP 1 ....

Comment: Some SQLs use `TOP 1`, some use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Should it display multiple employees if they tie for totalsales?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please show both sample data and desired results.

Comment: Not related to your question: why does the product table have an orderID column?